# How to use mock on ExecutorCompletionService

Tags: java, junit, mockito, completion-service

I am using ExecutorCompletionService and below method calls from that

```
Future<List<Student>> studentDetails = taskCompletionService.take();
Lis<Student> details =studentDetails.get()
```

Now am writing Junit and Mockito and I want to mock above two calls. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to stub for the `take` method of a mocked `taskCompletionService` then you could do something like this:

```
List<Student> studentDetails = Arrays.asList(fakeStudentDetail); 
when(taskCompletionService.take())
    .thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(studentDetails));
```

Comment: This must be accepted as the answer. It helped me resolve my issue. Thanks David!